# PowerShell access to Run dialog commands, or the common startup folder

Tags: windows, powershell, run-dialog

I've found how to open the Run dialog from PowerShell:

```
(New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application").FileRun()
```

And I know how to run a PowerShell command from there, and I'm aware of the difference between running a command from the Run dialog vs. running it from Command Prompt or PowerShell.

Having said that, my question is: How can I execute a command that works from the Run dialog from PowerShell instead?

Specifically, I'm interested in getting the location that would be opened when running `shell:common startup` from the Run Dialog, but to get it from a PowerShell script.

I came up with:

```
Join-Path -Path ([io.path]::GetFullPath($env:AllUsersProfile)) -ChildPath 'Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp'
```

But that seems to make too many assumptions about the path inside `$env:AllUsersProfile` and I'm unsure if that child path is guaranteed for any machine, or whether there would be variations.

Ideally, I'd just get the location used by `shell:common startup`, but if that's not possible, I'd like to know what the correct way to determine the common startup folder is.

(Note: technically, I don't need to know how to run the command that works from the `Run...` dialog, since doing so would just open the file manager at that location, and clearly I just want the location as a string.)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to answer my own question in part.

To get the common startup folder:

```
[Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::CommonStartup)
```

However, I'd still be interested to learn if there's a way to execute 'Run ...' dialog commands directly from PowerShell, even though I do not need it to solve my specific issue.

The above works for any CSIDL names, or rather `SpecialFolder` names, as listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0